# Returning a formatted string from a time structure

Tags: c++

I wrote a little structure for getting certain time information. This structure is a helper,
for my logging class im planning to write. Here is the code:

```
struct UTime
{
  char Month      [4];
  char DayOfMonth [3];
  char DayOfWeek  [4];
  char Year       [5];
  char Time       [9];
  char Full       [25];

  UTime()
  {
    this->refresh();
  }

  void refresh()
  {
    char      TimeBuffer[26] = {};
    time_t    RawTime        = 0;

    time(&RawTime);
    ctime_s(TimeBuffer, 26*sizeof(char), &RawTime);

    this->DayOfWeek[0]  = TimeBuffer[0];
    this->DayOfWeek[1]  = TimeBuffer[1];
    this->DayOfWeek[2]  = TimeBuffer[2];
    this->DayOfWeek[3]  = 0;

    this->Month[0]      = TimeBuffer[4];
    this->Month[1]      = TimeBuffer[5];
    this->Month[2]      = TimeBuffer[6];
    this->Month[3]      = 0;

    this->DayOfMonth[0] = TimeBuffer[8];
    this->DayOfMonth[1] = TimeBuffer[9];
    this->DayOfMonth[2] = 0;

    this->Time[0]       = TimeBuffer[11];
    this->Time[1]       = TimeBuffer[12];
    this->Time[2]       = TimeBuffer[13];
    this->Time[3]       = TimeBuffer[14];
    this->Time[4]       = TimeBuffer[15];
    this->Time[5]       = TimeBuffer[16];
    this->Time[6]       = TimeBuffer[17];
    this->Time[7]       = TimeBuffer[18];
    this->Time[8]       = 0;

    this->Year[0]       = TimeBuffer[20];
    this->Year[1]       = TimeBuffer[21];
    this->Year[2]       = TimeBuffer[22];
    this->Year[3]       = TimeBuffer[23];
    this->Year[4]       = 0;

    memcpy(this->Full, TimeBuffer, 25);
    this->Full[24] = 0;
  }
}; // struct UTime;
```

Now Id like to add a function wich returns a formatted version of the time information. 
For example:

```
std::string formatted = utime.get(Year, Month)
```

This function should return something like: **"2011 Nov"**, or another example:

```
std::string formated = utime.get(DayOfWeek, Time);
```

This function should return something like: **"Mon 20:43:24"**. Can anyone please point me in the most effecient way to do this? Im just not sure about effeciency because in a logger this function might get called alot. Thank you very much.

Comment: `asctime` is the function you seek.  Keep in mind that not all versions of the C-runtime library on all platforms are designed with multithread access in mind.  asctime returns a pointer to an internally static-allocated buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/). It supports lots of format

Comment: Thank you very much, this function looks promising. Im just worried about the character buffer this function needs, because you can nevver know the exact buffer size needed for the formatted string.

Comment: I am gonna go on a limb and say.. that for something like a date string.. a theoretical maximum can exist !! :).. Otherwise you can rely on the return value of strftime

Comment: @parapurarajkumar: The maximum (given the locale in the link) is `strlen(format)*12+1`, which is probably _much_ larger than needed: "%c%c%c%c%c%c%c"

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string utime::get(char* format) {
    std::string formatted;
    formatted.reserve(30);
    for( ; *format!='\0'; ++format) {
        if (*format != '%')
            formatted.append(*format);
        else {
            ++format;
            switch (*format) {
                case 'a': formatted.append(DayOfWeek); break;
                case 'b': formatted.append(Month); break;
                case 'd': formatted.append(DayOfMonth); break;
                case 'H': formatted.append(Time, 2); break;
                case 'M': formatted.append(Time+3, 2); break;
                case 'S': formatted.append(Time+6, 2); break;
                case 'x': formatted.append(Month); 
                          formatted.append(' '); 
                          formatted.append(DayOfMonth); 
                          formatted.append(' '); 
                          formatted.append(Year); 
                          break;
                case 'X': formatted.append(Time); break;
                case 'y': formatted.append(Year+2); break;
                case 'Y': formatted.append(Year); break;
                case '%': formatted.append('%'); break;
                default: throw std::logic_error("Unsupported string format");
            };
        }
    }
    return formatted;
}
```

This should be fairly fast since it reserves a fair amount of space, and simply appends chacters to the end of the already allocated buffer most of the time.  I highly recommend matching a standard formatting scheme like [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) as parapura rajkumar suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mooing Duck. Now i just have to choose wich method ill implement ;)